# While loop with try catch java

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, continue

So for some reason, in my while loop there is a try catch and when the catch fires, for some reason the code after the catch block is still executing with a continue statement inside the catch block. So I don't know what's happening.

```
    ArrayList<File> mapFileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    HashMap<String,Map> mapHash = new HashMap<String,Map>();

    // Player Variables
    ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
    Iterator<Player> playerIter;
    HashMap<String,Stats> statsMap = new HashMap<String,Stats>();
    File playerStatsFile;
    File newPlayerStatsFile;

    /*
     * Choose a map or make a new one
     */
    // Make a list of all existing files
    File mapFolder = new File("bin/maps/");
    // If the maps folder does not already exist, make it
    if(mapFolder.mkdir()){
        System.out.println("Maps folder does not exist. Creating.");
    }
    // For ever map file in the directory, save it to the map file list
    for(File fMap : mapFolder.listFiles()){
        if(fMap.getName().endsWith(".map")){
            mapFileList.add(fMap);
        }
    }
    // Load those maps into the mapHash HashMap
    Iterator<File> itMap = mapFileList.iterator();

        while(itMap.hasNext()){
        Map map = null;
        File fMap;
        // Get each map
        fMap = itMap.next();
        // Load them into memory and deserialize the map
        try{
            MapReader.openFile(fMap);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error: Cannot open file.");
            continue;
        }

        try{
            map = MapReader.readRecords();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: Problem with reading the map.");
            //System.exit(1);
            continue;
        }
        // Let the user know the map loaded successfully
        System.out.println("Map "+map.getName()+" loaded.");
        // Then store the map into the mapHash
        mapHash.put(map.getName().toLowerCase(), map);
    }
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: How do you know the program isn't simply looping to the next case like you designed and outputting from there?  Your error logging statements don't include any information that ties them to a specific fMap or map.

Comment: I have edited the code for you guys. If you need the MapWriter and MapReader classes, let me know.

Comment: Why cant you put try catch Outside the Loop.?? waht is the reason for that.?

Comment: It'd be nice if you could provide something we could cut and paste into our text editor and compile.

Comment: Because when I set all the .map files into the array list I want to go through each one and try to open, if I can't open it because it does not exist then go to the next item in the array list. If it opens then .readRecords() function I am trying to get the information about the map from the InputFileStream. If the file is corrupt (which is what I am testing) then it should throw the error which it does. Though when it comes back from the MapReader class and the Exception error is thrown & it doesn't continue with the while loop and instead prints out the corrupted map file.

Comment: I'd suggest to invest into a `sout` statement at the beginning of your loop, e.g. `System.out.println("Processing " + fMap);` to see if there is really something wrong - because I assume you'd run into a NPE if your code would really "skip" the `continue`...

Comment: Ah... I figured it out. You were right. It's still processing a file I thought I deleted. It's processing the ones correctly now that I added inside the MapReader.readRecords the MapReader.close() so if the user quits in the middle of making a Map the file is already closed. I also added in my MapWriter.addMapData a close statement after making the file so it can't be corrupted. My bad.